# Is Tweetdeck authentication really safe?

Tags: oauth, twitter

I have recently installed Tweetdeck, because my previous client stopped working.

In my custom client, and in the third party client I have used previously I had to setup authorize the application in my Twitter account and the use generated PIN to validate the client origin.

Now I have noticed that in Tweetdeck, I was only asked for my username and password for my account.

How can I verify that the executable is actually official from Twitter? And how can Tweetdeck access my Twitter account without my permission?

Answer (score 2):

> And how can Tweetdeck access my Twitter account without my permission?

You just *gave* Tweetdeck your "permission" by entering the username and password to your Twitter account...

I'm not very familiar with Twitter's API but it's definitely not as optimal as generating a PIN/token/whatever that limits access to one particular application in that it isn't as easy to revoke. However, I don't see any particular problems with it as long as you trust the application (and this doesn't change regardless of the authentication method.)

Comment: I was surprised that the username/password authentication was allowed. Because third party apps have to use the pin/token method, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Tweetdeck is an app which is run by Twitter.  That is why it doesn't require OAuth - it's part of Twitter's service offering.

If you want to make sure it's legitimate, there are three things you can do.

1. Set up [Two-Factor Authentication](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/getting-started-with-login-verification) (2FA).  When you try to log in to Tweetdeck, Twitter will send your mobile phone an SMS containing a unique login code.
2. Check that the website you're going to is linked directly from the [official Twitter web page](https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck).
3. Examine the SSL certificate on https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/ - does it belong to Twitter?